# Interactive dataframe scatter plot in a standalone script (without jupyter)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bokeh, pyviz

TL/DR : What I am trying to do:

1. Use dataframe (large existing dataset in df)
2. Run as a stand alone script (no jupyter)
3. Be able to easily interact/explore the data
4. Simple but full example (seen lots of code snippets that end up not working)

In the past I have been doing okay with dataframe, matplotlib and tkinter but I was starting to hit a performance wall with my data set size. It seems like with all the focus on data analysis and libraries recently that I thought I could make things look more modern and improve the interactivity with less code. Part of the problem seems to be too many ways of doing things that it is not clear what the current/best practices are or even how to do it it all.

I thought I was really close following the Bokeh examples but then I found that "Scatter" was not part of bokeh.plotting or bokeh.charts module anymore and was broken out into bkcharts project. Nope it was moved into holoviews or is it holoplot or hvplot... Lets dig in more, okay it seems like maybe it was moved into PyViz but uses hvplot with bokeh backend. I am so confused with all the libraries and tools my head is spinning.

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me a simple (but complete) example with the above requirements?

Here is the **OLD** much simplified example using matplotlib and dataframes (tkinter interactive stuff removed for simplicity):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data_ssv = """tone_amp_0  tone_freq_0     SNR
75.303        628.0  68.374
84.902       8000.0  61.292
92.856        288.0  70.545
70.000       2093.0  35.036
76.511       6834.0  66.952 """

data = pd.read_table(StringIO(data_ssv), sep="\s+", header=0)

x_points=data.loc[:, ['tone_amp_0']]
y_points=data.loc[:, ['SNR']]
z_points=data.loc[:, ['tone_freq_0']]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.scatter(x_points, y_points, c=z_points, cmap='hsv');

plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the closest I have come so far but the data is not plotting:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file,show
from io import StringIO

data_ssv = """tone_amp_0  tone_freq_0     SNR
75.303        628.0  68.374
84.902       8000.0  61.292
92.856        288.0  70.545
70.000       2093.0  35.036
76.511       6834.0  66.952 """

data = pd.read_table(StringIO(data_ssv), sep="\s+", header=0)

p = figure(x_axis_label='tone_amp_0', y_axis_label='SNR')

p.circle(x=data.loc[:, ['tone_amp_0']], y=data.loc[:, ['SNR']])

output_file("basic_interactive_plot.py.html")

show(p)
```

Comment: Use `ax.scatter(x_points, y_points, c=z_points.values, cmap='hsv')` instead. Not sure if `c` ever took a `Series` as input though.

Comment: The problem is that `data.loc[:, ['tone_freq_0']]` is a `DataFrame`. But the `c` argument only accepts series or numpy arrays. So `c = data['tone_freq_0']` would also work as expected.

Comment: In the new example, it would be `p.circle(x=data['tone_amp_0'].values, y=data['SNR'].values)`. Same reason as above.

Comment: Thanks Impo! Now that I have mostly figured it out I have found a really great [tutorial/resource](https://realpython.com/python-data-visualization-bokeh/). It takes you from the very begining to interactive plots with full working  examples! Can't say enough about it: https://realpython.com/python-data-visualization-bokeh/  I am debating about whether to delete this question or not.... Might be a good resource?

Comment: I also found the perfect example of what I want to do from the [bokeh site itself](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter/main.py). It just took me a REALLY long time to find it.